# Get week range dynamically based on custom day in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to generate week range for this month based on one day.
for example:
month start day is Friday (01-08-2014) and month end day is Sunday(31-08-2014) and custom day is Tuesday.

based on custom day I generate week range dynamically.

```
`var variable=[
{value:"01-08-2014 to 04-08-2014",name:"01-08-2014 to 04-08-2014"},
{value:"05-08-2014 to 11-08-2014",name:"05-08-2014 to 11-08-2014"},
{value:"12-08-2014 to 18-08-2014",name:"12-08-2014 to 18-08-2014"},
{value:"19-08-2014 to 25-08-2014",name:"19-08-2014 to 25-08-2014"},
{value:"26-08-2014 to 31-08-2014",name:"26-08-2014 to 31-08-2014"}
];`
```

another example 
suppose custom day is Sunday the range would become like

```
`var variable=[
{value:"01-08-2014 to 02-08-2014",name:"01-08-2014 to 02-08-2014"},
{value:"03-08-2014 to 09-08-2014",name:"03-08-2014 to 09-08-2014"},
{value:"10-08-2014 to 16-08-2014",name:"10-08-2014 to 16-08-2014"},
{value:"17-08-2014 to 23-08-2014",name:"17-08-2014 to 23-08-2014"},
{value:"24-08-2014 to 30-08-2014",name:"24-08-2014 to 30-08-2014"},
{value:"31-08-2014 to 31-08-2014",name:"31-08-2014 to 31-08-2014"}
];`
```

Comment: what is a custom day ??

Comment: User gives one day as input. we generate range based on that day.